# Specifically identify a batch script using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file

There are multiple batch scripts running on my PC and there is a need to kill only 1 specific job using a python program.
Tried the below mechanism using ***wmi*** package and it only returns the process name as **cmd.exe** for all the processes. How can I specifically identify the batch script I prefer?

```
import wmi

f = wmi.WMI()

for process in f.Win32_Process():

    print(process.name)
```

Comment: does the process have a window title?

Comment: yes, it does have a window title by using title command in batch scripts

Comment: `wmi` does not retrieve the window title, you'll have to call the `tasklist` command instead.